# How should I say we are closed for tomorrow?

Tags: indications-de-temps, travail, commerce

Well, I am a shop-seller and I want to tell to my customer that our shop is closed tomorrow. How should I say that?

I know that “fermé le dimanche” means “off for Sunday” or “closed on Sunday”, but I don't know how to say “I'm closed on Sunday”, or “our shop is closed on Sunday”?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pour une fermeture exceptionnelle prévisible :

> Le magasin sera fermé exceptionnellement demain, le *jj mmmmm AAAA*.

Pour annoncer le jour de la semaine pendant lequel le magasin est fermé :

> Fermeture hebdomadaire : le lundi.

Pancarte sur la porte d'entrée affichée le jour de fermeture :

> Fermé le lundi.

Answer (score 3):

“I'm closed on Sunday” is not entirely correct since you are referring to your person being closed on Sunday rather than your shop. The French translation is “Je suis fermé le dimanche”.

“Our shop is closed on Sunday” is more correct and translates into “Notre magasin est fermé le dimanche”.

Comment: In English, I've heard it, this is especially true of small businesses, as "We are…" as a whole, referring to the whole company, or enterprise. On est fermé…

Answer (score -2):

surely, if the shop was to be closed on one specific sunday it should be "CE MAGASIN FERA FERME LE DIMANCHE" if the shop is closed every sunday then surely " ce magasin est ferme dimanche"